# error: There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphoneos'

Tags: iphone

The error: `There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphoneos'`

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

double click on project file to open the Project info window. Set "Base SDK for All Configuration" to latest available sdk on your system.

Quit the xcode and open it again!

Comment: This worked for me, the trick was closing and re-opening XCode.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to build on xcode 4.

Select the Project, go to Build settings -> Add i386 under valid Architecture

```
ARCHS = $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)

SDKROOT = iphoneos3.1.3

ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO

SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS = iphonesimulator iphoneos

VALID_ARCHS = armv6 armv7 i386
```

Comment: I can't see Build Setting. where is it?

Comment: Enter Command(Windows) + 1, select the top most item (i.e the button/Tab showing the project Name) -> select the Project -> select Build Settings tab

Answer (score 0):

Open up your Xcode project and click on your project in the sidebar on the left. It should be labels your_project_name.xcodeproj
Once you click it, the main Xcode view should have a tab bar right at the top of the view. Right under the tool bar.  Here click "build settings" search for "base sdk" click on the drop down menu next to it and select the option highest up on the list.